# AWS Glue JSON CLassifier for numeric values

Tags: aws-glue

I have successfully used AS Glue to crawl an bunch of JSON files with the result being (almost) as I expected.  However, the numeric fields (from the JSON) have been catalogued as strings and not the float/ints etc they are.  This makes it a pain when querying in Athena when I want to query x >= 5, for example.

The JSON classifier I have is the basic classifier so I have not written a custom one.

Is there anyway I can get AWS GLue to recognise numeric values and catalogue them appropriately.

Cheers

Matt

Comment: You can cast string to a number in Athena queries: `select * from table1 where cast(x as BigInt) >= 5`

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the table in the glue console and click 'edit schema' in the top right, you should be able to click on a dropdown and change the type of the field